# How to describe changing rates of change (acceleration)

Tags: modifiers

Are the following sentences grammatically correct?

I want to describe speeds (fast/medium/slow) of change.

> increase at a faster/slower/very slow pace
>
> The increment is significant/slowing down/stagnant

Are there better sentences than these?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Can you add a little more context ? Thanks

Comment: In my context, I am going to describe the number of views on an online video, to describe the changes of views over time.

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are not grammatical.

We can use phrases like this:

> Views per day are increasing very fast.
>
> Online views are still increasing, but at a slower rate than last
>   month.
>
> Views per hour slowed last weekend.
>
> After growing quickly for six months, views per hour have remained
>   stagnant for the past three weeks.